# Comparing 2 lists and returning matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I have two functions that are related to one another - the first one removes characters that are the same and in the same position, and returns the ones that do not match:

```
def remove(l1, l2):
    r = []
    for char in range(len(l1)):
        if l1[char] != l2[char]:
            r.append(l1[char])
    return r
```

While this function goes through both lists, and removes the same values by using the previous function. Then using what's left it finds values that are the same in b (but they don't need to be in the same position).

```
def search(a, b):
    found = []
    elim = remove(a, b) 
    for char in elim:
        if char in b:
            find = 'y'
            found.append(find)
    return found
```

While I am able to return the correct amount of 'y's for the other examples I use, it breaks when I have more than one of the same value. If there is only 1 'V' in list 'b', but 2 in list 'a', I only want 1 'y' returned for it, not 2. Since I'm not sure where to go from here, my function returns this:

```
    search(['L', 'F', 'V', 'V'], ['V', 'F', 'O', 'R'])
Expected:
    ['y']
Got:
    ['y', 'y']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In `remove()`, you're adding ints to the list, not chars.

Comment: @Mr.bug that will turn it into a non-visible ascii character.

Comment: `r.append(char)` this is wrong , this will give index of char not char , you have to use  `r.append(l1[char])`

Comment: Is there an algorithm you're trying to implement here?

Comment: Something is wrong with your question.  The output you claim to see cannot actually come from the code you present.  The function `remove` populates a list that contains integers, and returns it.  The function `search` names this list `elim`, and then steps through it to see if any of its elements are in `b`.  None of them are, since `b` contains strings not integers.  The only possible returned value from `search` is [].

Comment: Sorry, I did make a mistake, I accidentally left out r.append(l1[char])!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def remove(l1, l2):
    r = []
    print l1
    print l2
    for char in range(len(l1)):
        if l1[char] != l2[char]:
            #the below line your code appending index of char , i am appending char
            r.append(l1[char])
    return r


def search(a, b):
    found = []
    elim = remove(a, b)
    print elim
      #the below line your code iterating through all chars of elim , i am looping through only unique ones using set 
    for char in set(elim):
        if char in b:
            find = 'y'
            found.append(find)
    return found
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
def remove(l1, l2):
    return [char1 for char1, char2 in zip(l1, l2) if char1 != char2]

def search(a, b):
    elim = remove(a, b)
    return ['y' for char in set(elim) if char in b]

print(search(['L', 'F', 'V', 'V'], ['V', 'F', 'O', 'R']))
```

output: `['y']`

I used `set(elim)` to remove the duplicates from the list created by `remove()`.

Comment: That seems right according to the problem description. Doesn't seem like there's any reason to wrap `set(elim)` in `list()` though.

Answer (score 1):

Change your second function to this:

```
def search(a, b):
    found = []
    elim = remove(a, b) 
    for char in elim:
        if a[char] in b:
            find = 'y'
            found.append(find)
            b.remove(a[char])
    return found
```

This takes into account that elim contains indexes rather than characters.  It will remove one 'V' from `b` every time a 'V' is indexed by `elim`.  But if both lists contains two 'V's you will get two 'y's.  I don't know if that's what you want.  Your statement of the problem isn't clear.  But I am pretty sure that you are a Python beginner and aren't ready to use the advanced concepts from the other answers.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity! As you said I'm a beginner so I have trouble conveying what I mean. And thank you for the explanation!